# ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference]... I can't boot Ubuntu

Tags: boot, acpi, initramfs

I boot Ubuntu. I was browsing on Firefox in Ubuntu and all of a sudden I got some error message, so I tried to reboot. Now when I try to reboot I get this message:

```
ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] ...
ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, while resolving operands for [Store] (20170831/dswexec-461)
ACPI Error: Method parse/ execution failed   
 \_PR.CPU0._AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (201708/psparse-550)
Busybox, v1.27.2 (ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3), built-in shell (ash)   
 Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands    
(initramfs)
```

Comment: Do you have automatic system updates turned on?

Comment: No,  i don't I'm used to be ask and then I allow the Updates

Answer (score 2):

At the black screen where the boot process has stopped press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to access a text-only virtual console.

To login from a virtual console:

1. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Check that the necessary proprietary graphics driver is installed. Run the following commands:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
sudo reboot
```

The `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` command installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies.

If you're unable to access a  virtual console, the next logical step is to check if it is caused by a hardware issue by booting to a Linux session from any Linux live USB. If that doesn't work either temporarily either remove or swap your computer's discrete graphics card if your computer has one to test if the graphics card is broken and needs to be replaced.

Comment: I can't boot, so that I don't come on.the terminal

Comment: I tried but I eaven come on the terminal on.this way. I come ever on.the same message. See question

Comment: I edited my answer with my reply to the above comment.

Comment: Have the same issue after a 21.04 to 21.10 upgrade. ubuntu-drivers isn't installing anything.

Comment: @MaxN To get ubuntu-drivers to work following the upgrade from 21.04 to 21.10 you could try running this command: `sudo apt update && sudo apt remove '^nvidia' && sudo apt autoremove &&  
sudo reboot `